# Filter rows by their minimal occurrence in all groups' combination

Tags: dplyr, filter, group-by

my problem is basic and its solution has been probably published somewhere, but I cannot find it. So I apologise in advance and I would be very grateful if you send me the link.

My data frame contains protein concentrations measured in patients suffering from two different diseases and falling into two different statuses. I aim to filter only proteins, including their concentrations, which have been measured in at least three patients of the same group combination (e.g., disease-A and status-Yes) AND measured in all group combinations (disease-status).

I have prepared an example table containing three proteins measured in 16 patients. Due to missing values, there are group combinations with less than three occurrences/measurements. My required table/output would contain only `xy` protein that were measured in three or more patients in each group combination and quantified in all four group combinations.

Below are my code and the code for the table.

I would like to thank everyone in advance for any comments.

```
data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                        patient = c(1L,
                                    2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,
                                    13L,14L,15L,16L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,
                                    7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,
                                    16L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,
                                    11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L),
                        disease = c("A",
                                    "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B",
                                    "B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A",
                                    "A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B",
                                    "B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A",
                                    "A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B",
                                    "B","B","B"),
                         status = c("yes",
                                    "yes","yes","yes","no","no","no",
                                    "no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no",
                                    "no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no",
                                    "no","no","no","yes","yes","yes",
                                    "yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes",
                                    "yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes",
                                    "yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no"),
                        protein = c("xy",
                                    "xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy",
                                    "xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy",
                                    "xy","zw","zw","zw","zw","zw","zw","zw",
                                    "zw","zw","zw","zw","zw","zw","zw",
                                    "zw","zw","gc","gc","gc","gc","gc",
                                    "gc","gc","gc","gc","gc","gc","gc","gc",
                                    "gc","gc","gc"),
                  concentration = c(58L,
                                    56L,59L,57L,52L,26L,24L,24L,26L,27L,
                                    24L,29L,21L,25L,56L,24L,NA,NA,79L,
                                    58L,56L,59L,55L,52L,26L,24L,24L,26L,
                                    58L,56L,59L,57L,52L,26L,24L,24L,26L,
                                    58L,56L,59L,57L,52L,26L,24L,NA,26L,
                                    NA,56L)
             )
```

```
data_subset <- data  %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(protein, disease, status) %>% 
  filter(n() >=3)
```

Comment: I did not see the problem with your code, what is wrong in the output?

Comment: Thank you @ViníciusFélix for your response. I need to filter out the table with only `xy` protein because its concentration was measured in all group combinations in at least three patients. Other proteins were not measured in all group combinations (e.b., `gc` protein was measured only in two samples in group combination B-no). Generally, I need to complete my code so that the table contains only proteins measured in all four combinations of groups.

Comment: I see, but your code already filter the combinations with 3 or plus combinations, I still don't see what is the problem. Can you provide a desired output?

Comment: When you run `data_subset %>% dplyr:: tally()`, you will see that `gc` and `zw` were measured only in tree group combinations (disease-status), but only `xy` was measured in all (four) group combinations. I need to adjust my code to filter out only `xy` protein because:
A)  it was measured in a minimum of three patients in a group combination (disease-status) (this is in my code; lines 3-4)
B) it was measured in all group combinations

Comment: The required table is the same as the original (data) but it contains only 16 lines with only `xy` protein.  Thank you for your assistance.